# Is pax-exam supposed to simply incorporate ordinary dependencies in the probe bundle?

Tags: pax-exam

If I have a dependency of scope 'test' that is not an OSGi bundle, should I expect pax-exam to simply incorporate it in the probe bundle, or do I need to explicitly wrap it?

I have a case where neither approach is working., and I'm trying to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probe bundle only includes the classes from the class path component containing the test class (usually just what's in `src/test/java` of your project).

You can customize the probe, or simply provision your test dependencies as separate bundle. The probe imports all packages dynamically.